# Accessible voice controlled e-reader?

Tags: ebook-readers, kindle-fire

I am looking for an e-reader or Ipad app for someone with mobility issues. A voice activated system would be ideal. For example, a verbal "Turn page" command instead of a physical swipe.

While the Kindle fire advertises voice control accessibility it's unclear to me if this is just a text-to-speech feature or if the system can be controlled with speech.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some videos about using custom voice commands in Windows for reading e-books on certain apps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjEOUxwLgFk&list=PLuMAX3X8HetJo1tPuZPkOUiQhdqacABUU&index=17&t=0s

and reading digital comics
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XvI-DUzXTI&list=PLuMAX3X8HetJo1tPuZPkOUiQhdqacABUU&index=18&t=0s

If Dragon Dictate could work on your iPad, it would be an expensive but workable solution. Otherwise, this autumn Apple is introducing voice control on Mac and iOS (
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqoXFCCTfm4)
which could possibly allow reading your books by saying "Space" or "Page down", or allowing you to click a button that does that action.

And in time I hope it will allow you to make some custom commands, or someone will make an add-on which allows you to do so.

My understanding of the Kindle Fire's voice control is it's just for the standard Alexa-style features, they don't do voice-activated page turning.

Answer (score 0):

If your person lives in the US, check into the NLS

> National Library Service (NLS) is a free braille and talking book library service for people with temporary or permanent low vision, blindness, or a physical disability that prevents them from reading or holding the printed page.

https://www.loc.gov/nls/

They have ereaders and booksthat specially built for both blind and most levels of disability.

The reader and the books are free and delivered by mail to the home of the individual.

Answer (score 0):

While not a voice activated system, we ended using the [Switch accessibility controls](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201370) in the Ipad. This allowed us to connect a bluetooth keyboard to the Ipad and program gestures which are be activated by the keyboard. For example, we set the spacebar to a "swipe right" gesture which works perfectly for reading within the ebooks app.

Alternatively, the switch controls can use the camera and take head gestures as inputs. This feature is also compatible with other [third party accessories](https://www.ablenetinc.com/technology/switches) (ie joysticks, a range of buttons etc..) through the headphone jack or bluetooth.

(This worked well for us because as are not US citizens and can't access the NLS services)